# How to install over existing Android app on device using adb?

Tags: android, adb

During development, I use something like

```
$ adb -s 192.168.1.77:5555 uninstall com.myApp.app

$ adb -s 192.168.1.77:5555 install /path/to/android-debug.apk
```

to uninstall the existing app, then push and install the updated app to my device. However, this seems to erase my existing data associated with the app so that each time I run the updated app I need to input the new data again. However, simply running the install command gives:

```
[ 10%] /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
```

With iOS you can simply install your updated app over the existing app on the device.

What is the equivalent for Android preferably using `adb`?

Edit: This question is really similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414786/adb-update-a-non-market-apk), but I think this should be kept because the way my question is phrased will help many people trying to find an answer that are coming from a different angle– the angle being of reinstalling/overwriting versus updating.

Comment: `adb install -r /path/to/android-debug.apk`

Comment: @ymonad Works like a charm. I see all the flag options now. Thanks. If you post this answer I'll give you the cred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adb update a non-market apk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414786/adb-update-a-non-market-apk)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from `adb --help`

```
adb install [-lrtsdg] <file>
        - push this package file to the device and install it
         (-l: forward lock application)
         (-r: replace existing application)
         (-t: allow test packages)
         (-s: install application on sdcard)
         (-d: allow version code downgrade (debuggable packages only))
         (-g: grant all runtime permissions)
```

Therefore you can just add `-r` option

```
$ adb -s 192.168.1.77:5555 install -r /path/to/android-debug.apk
```