# Preserving old application data while running 'flutter install'

Tags: android, flutter

This question may relate both to the Flutter framework itself and to the Android development generally - I don't have enough knowledge in either to find out.

My problem is in updating the demo version of the app I'm developing on my phone. Each time I install the release version of the application using `flutter install` command, it first uninstalls the existing one, resulting in loss of data.

Is it possible to preserve this data between installations, without resorting to data backup through *adb*?

Comment: Have you tried [Install over existing Android app on device using adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39842874/295004) with the release version of the apk?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I haven't, but I will now, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @MorrisonChang that worked, please add your suggestion as an answer so I could mark it as accepted one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Flutter uses the Android SDK, all of the Android tools are available via the command line.

The Android command line tool `adb` is used to push and pull data and apks.

Replacing an existing app as if it were an update is a necessary part of testing (i.e. data schema changes, database upgrades) so to upgrade use:

`$ adb install -r /path/to/myapp.apk`

See: [How to install over existing Android app on device using adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39842874/295004)